# VuetifyJS toolbar overlays content as soon as fixed prop gets added

Tags: javascript, vue.js, toolbar, vuetify.js

I need to use a **fixed** toolbar (with an extension). Problem is that The toolbar overlays the content as soon as the **fixed** prop gets added. How to place the content below the toolbar?
CodePen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpgjyd?&editors=101

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-toolbar
      color="primary"
      dark
      fixed
      extended         
    >
      <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title slot="extension">Title</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>search</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-layout>
    <v-flex xs1 >
      +++ FIRST LINE +++ 
      [lots of text...]
      </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Your only requirement is that the toolbar is always stuck to the top of the viewport?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One solution is adding `app` to `v-toolbar` and wrap v-layout inside `v-content`

```
<v-toolbar
      app
      color="primary"
      dark
      fixed
      extended         
    >
...
</v-toolbar>
<v-content>
  <v-layout>
  </v-layout>
</v-content>
```

Demo https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/mGdbeN?editors=1010

References: [Vuetify application layout tutorial](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/pre-defined)

Comment: Since version 2.0.0 v-toolbar isn't fixable use v-app-bar https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars

Answer (score 1):

Add `app` to `v-toolbar` and wrap `v-layout` inside `v-content`

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get exactly your question, is this what you wanted to achieve:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted(){
    var fixedElement = document.getElementsByClassName('v-toolbar--fixed')[0];
    var layout = document.getElementsByClassName('layout')[0];
    layout.style = "padding-top: "+ fixedElement.offsetHeight + 'px'; 
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/Younes_k/pen/LJEjOL